# Can't hide form. Window appear after completion of form constructor

Tags: c#, forms

I need a hidden form with displayed console as user interface (don't ask why, I don't need another way). All methods is in form class.

So, I created Windows forms project with console output. Everything works fine, but i can't hide form.

Start form:

```
static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
```

And here is form constructor:

```
public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Visible = false;
            //here i try to find one other window by caption 
            //using FindWindow() WinAPI method
            this.Text = "Generated window title";
            //find handle of this window:
            int currentWindowHandle = (int)FindWindow(null, title);
            //after this moment form is again visible
        }
```

To hide form I use this code:

```
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value) {
            if (!this.IsHandleCreated) {
                value = false;
                CreateHandle();
            }
            base.SetVisibleCore(value);
        }
```

Form starts hidden but after constructor is completed, it's visible again.

I tried to figure out at what exact moment it happens:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            Debug.WriteLine(m.Msg);
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

I got this as output:

```
//waited a while
...
24  x0018 = SHOWWINDOW 
528 x0210 = PARENTNOTIFY 
14  x000E = GETTEXTLENGTH 
13  x000D = GETTEXT 
70  x0046 = WINDOWPOSCHANGING
```

Before this I already get many times messages 13, 14, 70. As i get last 70 msg, after `base.WndProc(ref m);` window appears.

Searched explanation of messages:

> SHOWWINDOW = 0x0018
>
> The WM_SHOWWINDOW message is sent to a window when the window is about to be hidden or shown.
>
> PARENTNOTIFY = 0x0210
>
> The WM_PARENTNOTIFY message is sent to the parent of a child window when the child window is created or destroyed, or when the user clicks a mouse button while the cursor is over the child window. When the child window is being created, the system sends WM_PARENTNOTIFY just before the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function that creates the window returns. When the child window is being destroyed, the system sends the message before any processing to destroy the window takes place.

Definitely, something does not let me to keep this window hidden? I don't get it. I don't send any messages to this application. I just run it and look.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `this.Hide()`

```
public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this may this helps you solve your problem

```
Form1 frm = new Form1;
frm.Hide();
```

Or

```
frm.visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

And after all of this i found alternative solution.

Maybe this is useless to community. But someone can meet same problem so i will post it. If this question get -5 i will delete it.

You can just:

```
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Wonder, why it don't work sometimes:

```
    this.Visible = false;
```

Comment: You found your answer in same time you asked a question :)